# How to setup Firefox and KeePassXC in a flatpak and get the KeePassXC-Browser add-on to work?

Tags: password, firefox, flatpak, password-store, keepassx

If KeePassXC is sandboxed [in a Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC), browsers can only access it, if they are *not* sandboxed, i.e. installed as an deb/rpm package or similar on the host.
Sandboxing both the browser, i.e. [Firefox](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox), and KeePassXC – or at least the browser and installing KeePassXC natively, which you'd actually want for security reasons – is not possible.

TL;DR:

- this should work out-of-the box: Firefox (host-installed), KeePassXC (flatpak from flathub)
- this does not: Firefox (sandboxed), KeePassXC (host or sandboxed, does not matter)

So how to make that communication work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Background

If you just want the solution, you can skip this part. But for the curious, I'll explain the problems we face:

- KeePassXC creates an UNIX socket in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/kpxc_server` for applications to listen too. `keepassxc-proxy` is started – via [native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) – *by the browser* (triggered by the add-on `keepassxc-browser@keepassxc.org`, i.e. KeePassXC-Browser) and tries to listen on that socket to find messages.
- If Firefox is not sandboxed, that proxy can start as usual. The only thing it possibly needs to do is get into the KeePassXC flatpak.
- Flathub KeePassXC [has a patch](https://github.com/flathub/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC/blob/master/patch/keepassxc/0003-Support-KeePassXC-Browser-Flatpak-environments.patch) that allows the keepassxc-proxy to be started via `flatpak run`, i.e. Firefox can now run a
- That is, so far, why Firefox installed on the host does work…
- Now why it does not work if Firefox is installed as a flatpak: The very good official [Firefox flatpak by Mozilla](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox) really does have few permissions for being a browser. E.g. it does not have any generic access to the file system (it uses [portals](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/portal-api-reference.html)). Anyway, whatever it does, it cannot do one thing: [Spawn a process on the host or in another flatpak](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/283).

So we could solve that by making wrapper scripts and [using flatpak-spawn](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-spawn) to let Firefox escape it's sandbox. However, seeing how lovely and quite securley the Firefox sandbox is already built, I would not dare to destroy that security for such a feature. After all, from a security POV you could then also just install Firefox on the host, yet again.
So glad news ahead: **This solution preserves all sandboxes and security aspects!**

However, even if we've solved the fact of Firefox having to run the proxy, there are more problems. To spoiler, this are the main points we need to solve:

1. Starting keepassxc-proxy by Firefox (solution: we run it inside the Firefox sandbox)
2. Allowing Firefox to access the socket of KeePassXC
   Note: At that step, you can already run the variation: Firefox (sandboxed), KeePassXC (host-installed)
3. Exposing the UNUX socket from the KeePassXC flatpak to other applications outside of the Flatpak. (solution: an symbolic link)

## Current workaround

v1.2

Tested with: Fedora 32, `org.mozilla.firefox` v75 from flathub, `org.keepassxc.KeePassXC` v2.5.4 from flathub

### Starting keepassxc-proxy by Firefox

1. Worst things first: We need the `keepassxc-proxy` as a binary, because we want to have it run inside of the Firefox flatpak. Good for us: it has not many depenencies and is available as a stand-alone application.

   1. So I chose the [Rust proxy application](https://github.com/varjolintu/keepassxc-proxy-rust) (because why should not I? ). If you trust me, you can get my compiled binary below, just skip to two steps ahead.
   2. Clone the git repo and compile it (run `cargo build --release`).
   3. You find the result in `./target/release`.
      The `keepassxc-proxy` binary, version [`211ae91`](https://github.com/varjolintu/keepassxc-proxy-rust/commit/211ae91), compiled with rustc 1.43.0 (the current stable in Fedora 32) for x86_64 (and if it helps and you wanna know more [that `.rustc_info.json`](https://gist.github.com/rugk/9709fc34b3763edaa00dd1f0c90a2837)).
      And altghough [Rust is not (yet) totally reproducibly compiling](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34902) I did got the same bit-by-bit result on two machines with Fedora 32. The SHA-256 hash is `c5c4c6c011a4d64f7e4dd6c444dcc70bee74d23ffb28c9b65f7ff6d89a8f86ea`.
      So if you are in a risky mood, you can **[just download my keepassxc-proxy binary here](https://github.com/rugk/keepassxc-proxy-rust/releases/download/211ae91/keepassxc-proxy)**. ([hosted by GitHub ;P](https://github.com/rugk/keepassxc-proxy-rust/releases/tag/211ae91))
2. Now we need to tell Firefox about the new binary.

   1. Go to `~/.var/app/org.mozilla.firefox/.mozilla/native-messaging-hosts`. Actually, the `native-messaging-hosts` likely does not exist yet, so do create it.
   2. Create a file `org.keepassxc.keepassxc_browser.json` in there, and paste in the following content:

      ```json
      {
          "allowed_extensions": [
              "keepassxc-browser@keepassxc.org"
          ],
          "description": "KeePassXC integration with native messaging support, workaround for flatpaked Firefox, see https://is.gd/flatpakFirefoxKPXC",
          "name": "org.keepassxc.keepassxc_browser",
          "path": "/home/REPLACE_WITH_USERNAME/.var/app/org.mozilla.firefox/.mozilla/native-messaging-hosts/keepassxc-proxy",
          "type": "stdio"
      }
      ```

      Note that only absolute paths work (I guess), so replace `REPLACE_WITH_USERNAME` with your `$USER` name, so that the paths leads to it's own working dir.
   3. You see what I am doing: We now place the downloaded/compiled `keepassxc-proxy` **in the same dir**. Obviously, you could use any other path there, but this was the first one that is obviously accessible by Firefox and you have everything in one place. (If you have better suggestions, feel free to let me know.)
      *Note:* Remember to make it executable (`chmod +x`)  if it is not, already.

### Allowing Firefox to access the socket

KeePassXC, by default, creates it's socket in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/kpxc_server`. So this is what we need to give the Firefox flatpak access to (read-only is obviously enough).

Fortunately, this is easy. Just run:

```
$ sudo flatpak override --filesystem=xdg-run/kpxc_server:ro org.mozilla.firefox
```

**Hooray!:** For those, who install KeePassXC **on the host** (without any sandbox/flatpak), this is enough. Start KeePassXC and *then* Firefox and it should be able to connect. :tada:
Please note the "existing problems" section at the bottom, though.

Continue, if you also want to run KeePassXC in a flatpak.

### Exposing the UNIX socket from the KeePassXC flatpak

Note: Again skip to the bullet point (point 1) below, if you don't wanna know the technical background.

The flatpaked KeePassXC from Flathub creates it's Unix socket in the location flatpaks should do so, in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/app/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC/kpxc_server`. (If it would use `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` directly like the "native" KeePassXC, it would only exist in the sandbox.)

As we know, the usual keepassxc-proxy expects the file at `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/kpxc_server`. To solve this, we just create a symbolic link.
As you can verify, this actually solves our problem. For some very strange reason, the Flatpak sandbox now allows Firefox (and all other flatpaks! Just FYI, be aware of that.) to see that UNIX socket file.
As it should turn out later, this does not work when you move that symbolic link anywhere else (even another file name already prevents it from working – I've tried a lot of things.).

However, `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is usually deleted at shutdown. So we need to recreate it at startup/user login. Good for us there, is already a tool for that. (you could also mangle with shell scripts in your autostart of course, but that is ugly.)
That's why we make use of [systemd-tmpfiles](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html). (The man page for [tmpfiles.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d) is more useful for us actually.)

1. Go to `~/.local/share/user-tmpfiles.d`. Again, there is a high chance the `user-tmpfiles.d` dir does not exist yet. If so… well… you know what to do…
2. Now download and place the following config file in there: **[kpxc_server.conf](https://gist.github.com/rugk/96b778603037a6bc5a690d7bac178c79)**
   This is basically a config file for `systemd-tmpfiles` that says it to create that symbolic link for the user.
3. Reboot, so `systemd-tmpfiles` can apply the changes and create the config file. (Alternatively, you can also manually run `systemd-tmpfiles --user --create` to apply the changes.)

**Hooray!:** Afterwards start the KeePassXC flatpak and *then* Firefox and it should be able to connect. :tada:

Please note the "existing problems" section below.

### Existing problems

- Firefox, for some reason, cannot see the `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/kpxc_server` file, **if** the file (respectively it's symbolic link target) does not exist yet.
  In practise, this results in **one big disadvantage:** You **always** need to start **KeePassXC *before* Firefox**.
- For some more strange reason, if you have this workaround setup, the usual way that you run a non-flatpaked native Firefox and connect it by spawning the proxy inside the flatpak (like `flatpak run org.keepassxc.KeePassXC`) may not work. Delete the symbolic link again to make this work.

## Debugging tips

- In Firefox use `about:debugging` to access add-on internals. `keepassxc-browser@keepassxc.org` is the add-on ID. It actually also logs failed attempts. Note there are different results (logs and visibly) when it cannot start the proxy vs when it can start the proxy, but no connection suceeds (because the UNIX socket is not there, e.g.)
- To manually get into the flatpak and "see" in a shell what it has access to/looks like, use something like `flatpak run --command=/bin/sh org.mozilla.firefox`.
- To check whether the socket file is accessible (a symbolic link can point to a non-existant file) just `cat` it and you'll see a strange error that `cat` cannot find a resource

## Things I've tried

Things that do **not** work:
*Preserved for future solutions and better™ workarounds.*

- all things in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/app` are highly sandboxed, even with flatpak overrides I could not get the Firefox flatpak to read the content of the `../org.keepassxc.KeePassXC` dir. Even with crazy symbolic links in it's own dir. (Do try it though, maybe you'll make it! At least you'll learn something. :wink:.)
- what works though is: You can override the KeePassXC flatpak to get access to Mozilla. Only **write** access possible though! Thus, if it would place the proxy there (again: symbolic links here don't work!), Firefox could also read it.
- The symbolic link must be created by an application outside of the sandbox. Inside of it, it's again – sandboxed – and one only visible inside of it.

## Final notes

That took quite some time to figure it out.

I do try to continue improving this workaround and find solutions in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flathub/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC/issues/29). It's best to follow there, if you are interested.

---

I've cross-posted this question and answer [in the Fedora community](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-run-firefox-and-keepassxc-in-a-flatpak-and-get-the-keepassxc-browser-add-on-to-work/19452?u=rugk) and [in the Flathub forum](https://discourse.flathub.org/t/how-to-run-firefox-and-keepassxc-in-a-flatpak-and-get-the-keepassxc-browser-add-on-to-work/437/2?u=rugk).

Comment: Debian bullseye, Keepassxc 2.6.2 (no sandbox), Firefox 100.0 (flatpak) and KeePassXC-Browser Version: 1.7.12: the socket name appeared as `xdg-run/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC.BrowserServer` instead of `kpxc_server`. Changed flatpak override command accordingly. Otherwise, these instructions seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[rugk's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584522/531755) is on the right track, but I had to change a [few things](https://ebsteblog.wordpress.com/2022/06/28/connecting-flatpak-firefox-and-keepassxc/) to get it to work with keepassxc 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 22.04:

- the repo is outdated, use https://github.com/varjolintu/keepassxc-proxy-rust instead
- I had to create a statically linked binary because of mismatch of libc available in host and flatpak
- the path in the .json file needs to be an absolute path from the perspective of the flatpak
- because of the changed socket name the flatpak override command needs to be adjusted

See my [blog post](https://ebsteblog.wordpress.com/2022/06/28/connecting-flatpak-firefox-and-keepassxc/) for detailed instructions.

Comment: You have a different setup, please delete It does not offer any insight into the original question/answer.

Comment: @number9 Why is it a different setup? The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584522/531755) talks about having Firefox installed as flatpak and keepassxc natively. The only difference is that I use different because current versions - and I have Ubuntu instead of Fedora, but both the accepted and my answer are not specific to any particular operating system. Why does it not offer any insight if this is the way I got it to work and the original answer didn't work? I'd be very happy if I'd have found a working answer somewhere instead of me spending hours getting things to work.

Comment: @decocijo Thanks for the updated answer and blog post with the rust flags for static compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @decocijo and @rugk answer, this is a working example of Chrome based browsers (Vivaldi) and also provides a more straight forward way for Firefox.

[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/cdpb/fd2dbecdb4a08d79da6c08d8a65dd97c)

```
git clone https://github.com/varjolintu/keepassxc-proxy-rust
cd keepassxc-proxy-rust

# compile
# add deps if needed
sudo dnf install gcc rustup
rustup-init
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
cp target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/keepassxc-proxy ~/.var/app/com.vivaldi.Vivaldi/config/vivaldi/NativeMessagingHosts/

# modify flatpaks
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=xdg-run/app/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC:ro com.vivaldi.Vivaldi
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=xdg-run/org.keepassxc.KeePassXC:ro com.vivaldi.Vivaldi
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=/var/home/m8/.var/app/com.vivaldi.Vivaldi/config/vivaldi/NativeMessagingHosts org.keepassxc.KeePassXC

# modify keepassxc browser path
In the KeePassXC UI.
- Tools
  - Settings
    - Browser Integration
      - General
        - Enable Browser Integration
        - Tick Vivaldi
      - Advanced
        - Use a custom location
          - Chromium
            - ~/.var/app/com.vivaldi.Vivaldi/config/vivaldi/NativeMessagingHosts
```